# Infrastructure concerns in domain services

Tags: database, domain-driven-design

I've got a domain service that needs to apply some rules affecting the infrastructure layer because they are domain requirements. In short: Infrastructure policies & strategies.

```
public MyService : IMyService {

    private readonly RetryPolicy<ConnectionErrorDetectionStrategy> _retryPolicy;
    // there might be other strategies for other concerns
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public MyService(IRepository repository) {
        _repository  = repository;
        _retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<ConnectionErrorDetectionStrategy>();
    }

    public Do() {

        _repository.CrudMagic();
        _retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() => _repository.Commit());

    }

}
```

The requirement was to ensure that under some cases (*case*), the software should make several retries (*strategy*) when the application fails to connect (*policy*) to the database. However this feels akward because the domain isn't aware of what a connection is (the whole DAL could be even a mock!). How can I ensure that the correct strategy is being applied for this particular service / case?

Answer (score 0):

Use Proxy or Decorator.

```
class MyService : IMyService {...}
class MyRetryService: IMSyService {
    private readonly IMSyService target; //inject MyService
    private readonly RetryPolicy<ConnectionErrorDetectionStrategy> _retryPolicy;
}
```

Inject mock as target(IMSyService) when unit testing. Just expect and verify target's invocations. The target should be invoked as many times as the policy specified if failure encounted and the retry works.

An alternative is AOP (if there is mature framework/lib on your platform). The test approach is the same.

Comment: "*the target should be invoked as many times*" How do you mean this? RetryPolicy is a stateful application layer service which automatically repeats a certain action if e.g. a exception is thrown. If I would invoke the target (IMyService.Do()) as many times as specified in the policy, I would end up having x entries inside my database (or even more exception due to the entity already existing).

Comment: Also, separating the desired action (commit()) from Do() and put it on the interface is also wrong because my service doesn't allow a client to commit. The commit is just a part of a client action.

Comment: Does the RetryPolicy aim to retry some action for a predefined times when something goes wrong?And just execute the action only once if everything goes fine?

Comment: Yes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.transientfaulthandling.retrypolicy.aspx

Comment: Is there some mock frameworks in c# that could define and verify expect invocation? If yes, mock the repository in your test cases, define repository.commit invoked once in happy path case, define repository.commit invoked x times(depends on your retry config) in failure cases.